# Python beginner having some issues with thread here

Tags: python-3.x

I am progressing on my project of a word puzzle. It's almost finished but I face some troubles with my thread that countdown and shut the program when time's up.

Here is a part of my code

```
def lose():
    print("\n\nBtzzzzz!!! Times up!")
    print(f.renderText('Game Over'))
    quit()

    # A thread that excecute lose when time's up
    t = Timer(3.0, lose)
    t.start()
    print("\nGuess a word that contains all of the given letters.")
    print("The letters are: ", end="")
    count = 1
    for question in Question_list:
        print(question, end="")
        if count < level:
            print(" - ", end="")
            count += 1
    print()
    print(correct_ans)
    while True:
        try:
            answer = input("Your answer: ")
        except ValueError:
            quit()

        if len(answer) > level + 2 and level != 5:
            print(f"The range of letters for the word in this level is between {str(level)} and {str(level + 2)}.")

        if answer == correct_ans:
            answer_list.clear()
            t.cancel()
            if level != 5:
                print("Good job! Here comes the next one.")
                time.sleep(1)
            break
        else:
            print("Wrong answer.Please try again.")
```

This is the output.

[image]

It seems like that it still executes the while loop once before it finally ends

Comment: Please be more specific than "I face some troubles".

Comment: `quit()` ends the thread it's in, it doesn't end the program unconditionally.

Comment: The thread doesn't stop the program, instead, a value error for "Your answer" occurs.

Comment: So, I try to fix it with exception. It doesn't throw an error now, but the loop still execute once before the program ends

Comment: @ShadowRanger What should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

So, first off, use `sys.exit()`, not `quit()` in actual scripts ([`quit()` is added by the `site` module and isn't guaranteed to exist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#constants-added-by-the-site-module); even when it exists, it's overridden by some interpreter wrappers to do different things; `quit()` is intended solely for interactive use).

Secondly, `quit()` (and `sys.exit()`) ends the thread it is in (assuming nothing catches the `SystemExit` exception it's implemented in terms of), it doesn't end the *program*; the thread terminating has no effect on the main thread, which continues running, so the program doesn't actually die.

Possible solutions involve:

1. Polling `t.is_alive()` in your loop, so your loop stops running when the `Timer` stops
2. Moving your loop to a `daemon` thread, and having the main thread sleep for X seconds then exit (with the `daemon` thread terminating on its own when all non-daemon threads have exited)
3. (I recommend against it) Replace `quit()` with `os._exit()`, which forcibly terminates the program (this can do bad things if other threads were relying on `with` or `try`/`finally` blocks, or `atexit` or whatever to do proper cleanup)
4. Avoid threads entirely and just record `time.monotonic()` when you enter the loop, and check if you've exceeded the time limit as needed.
5. Have the thread explicitly call `sys.stdin.close()` before dying (not 100% this will work, but it *should* interrupt `input` calls by taking away the source of input; you'll probably need to handle the exception this causes in the main thread)

There are other options, but they all boil down to either sharing information between threads, implicitly (like #1 or #5) or explicitly (with an `Event` variable or the like), forcibly dying when the time is up (#2 or #3), or avoiding threads entirely (#4).